# Can I change the XML comment template in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xml-comments

I would like to add a `<tag>` or two to the "standard" template of XML comment tags provided by Visual Studio 2010. When I type `///` in my source, I'd like to see the new tags included
with the default tags in the inserted comment block. How do I do this in a C# environment?

Answer (score 7):

We've done some research on this topic in the past (for one of our customers) and while XML Comment templates can be customized for VB - see [post by Lisa Feigenbaum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx) - this doesn't work for C#.

Lisa and Visual Studio team folks confirmed the trick doesn't work in C# in VS10.

There is a request to add this to C# Editor in VS11. If you care for the feature to get into VS, please vote here - http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2709987-xml-comments-schema-customization-in-c-

In the meantime our customer opted to use our [GhostDoc Pro](http://submain.com/ghostdoc/) product as it allows just any XML Comment customization using a T4 template.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this could be customized for VB.NET! That would have saved me a lot of time—thanks for the link.